# Find minimum of odd quadratic expression

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, quadratics, problem-solving

I need to minimise the following function of $\alpha$
$$
f(\alpha) = (2\alpha - 1)A - 2\sqrt{\alpha(1-\alpha)}B
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are independent of $\alpha$.

#### My Attempt

The derivative is
$$
\frac{d}{d\alpha} f(\alpha) = 2A - \frac{1-2\alpha}{\sqrt{\alpha(1-\alpha)}}B
$$
Setting this to zero we get
$$
\frac{d}{d\alpha} f(\alpha) = 0 \implies 2\sqrt{\alpha(1-\alpha)}A = (1-2\alpha) B
$$
Squaring both sides we get
$$
(2\alpha - 2\alpha^2) A = (1 + 4\alpha^2 - 4\alpha) B
$$
Rearranging we get
$$
\alpha^2(2A + 4B) + \alpha(-2A-4B) + B = 0 
$$
Using the quadratic formula
$$
\begin{align}
\alpha_{1, 2} 
&= \frac{2A + 4B \pm \sqrt{4A^2 + 16B^2 + 16 AB - 4B(2A + 4B)}}{2B} \\
&= \frac{2A + 4B \pm \sqrt{4A^2 + 8AB}}{2B}
\end{align}
$$
If I plug this into $f(\alpha)$ I don't get a nice expression and I am struggling with the second derivative test.

#### Second derivative

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{d\alpha^2} f(\alpha)
&= -B\left(- \frac{2}{\sqrt{\alpha(1-\alpha)}} -\frac{(1-2\alpha)^2}{2\sqrt{\alpha^3(1-\alpha)^3}}\right)
\end{align}
$$

#### Following comment hint

Setting $\alpha = \cos^2\theta$ then we have
$$
\begin{align}
f(\theta) 
&= (2\cos^2\theta - 1) A - 2\sqrt{\cos^2\theta(1-\cos^2\theta)} \\
&= \cos(2\theta) A - 2\cos\theta \sin \theta B \\
&= \cos(2\theta) A - \sin(2\theta) B
\end{align}
$$
The derivative with respect to $\theta$ would then be
$$
\frac{d}{d\theta} f(\theta) = -2\sin(2\theta) A -2\cos(2\theta) B
$$
Setting this to zero gives
$$
-\frac{\sin(2\theta^*)}{\cos(2\theta^*)} = \frac{B}{A}
$$
which means
$$
\theta^* = \frac{1}{2}\text{arc} \tan\left(-\frac{B}{A}\right)
$$

Comment: “*I don't get a nice expression*” why you assume so?

Comment: @CroCo Do you mean why do I assume I should get a nice expression, or why do I assume that plugging it in will not give a nice expression?

Comment: "Squaring both sides we get" - You forgot to square the $2$ on the left.

Comment: And you forgot to square $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Put $\alpha=\cos^{2}(\theta)$. The function becomes $A\cos (2\theta)-B\sin(2 \theta)$. Use C-S inequality to show that the minimum is $-\sqrt {A^{2}+B^{2}}$.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried to reproduce the result, added it to the question. I'm unsure how to proceed

Comment: Doesn't that only hold for the domain $|\alpha| \le 1$? Wouldn't we also need to show the minimum doesn't occur on $\alpha \lt -1$ or $\alpha \gt +1$ ?

Comment: @smci - Look at the square root defining $f$. The domain is $[0,1]$.

Comment: @mr_e_man: I know about the square root; If the assumption that $\alpha$ was positive is wrong, we get a complex solution for $\alpha$. But I'm asking why we can just dismiss almost the entire domain $|\alpha| > 1$ without at least hand-wave justifying why the minimum can't occur there. Can you respond to that?

Comment: @smci - You cannot minimize a complex function, as the complex numbers are not ordered. We're dealing with real numbers here. Hence $\alpha(1-\alpha)\geq0$; that is, $0\leq\alpha\leq1$.

Comment: @mr_e_man: oh you mean the domain is implicitly understood to be restricted to $0 \le \alpha \le 1$ from the $\sqrt{\alpha(1-\alpha)}$ term. Ok thanks for the reminder.